# PCIE Finger Torn off Graphics Card

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

I have a 3080 ti FE that has been relegated to the bin due to mishandling during shipment. I will attach photos of all the visible damage, but I am mostly concerned with what I think is pin B65 being torn off. Can anyone chime in and let me know how worried I should be about this card not working, frying my mobo/system, etc?

Here's an Imgur album with photos: https://imgur.com/a/8OuoIkr

Comment: Oh god, that poor thing.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, It should be fine. I'm actually a little more concerned over the dent in the circuit board (what would do that!) causing the board not to fit in the slot.

Pin B65 is a ground pin - so in theory, as long as *some* ground pin is connected you will have ground, and if you put the card in all the way, it *should* make contact.

I'm still concerned since high and GPUs are generally shipped in padded boxes - and we don't know what other damage there would be. I'd be more inclined to think a slightly faulty circuit board that wasn't inspected properly (or passed as acceptable) than assuming transport damage if I saw the card without the context you've given

I *think* it should be fine, but I'd be a little weary of staking my reputation (or someone elses PC) on that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified what I meant by the shipping mishandling. It was sent while installed in a PC build. The mobo's PCIE slot had bent pins, but overall the visible damage was not exceptional.

As for the dent in the circuit board, thank you for pointing out its importance. Do you think I could test it in a working mobo, or would I run the risk of system failure?

Comment: There's nothing that calls out to me as being a 'huge' risk - burn marks for example. Stuff I *don't* see would concern me - could traces or the board be damaged by torquing forces for example. In general computers are pretty good at 'localising' damage and shutting down before things go boom, but there's a lot here that I don't see.  What I *see* looks fine. What I'm hearing leads me to think what I see isn't the full story

Comment: I get your meaning. When I took the rig to the local shop for a once over, they came back to me with an inconclusive result about the card, so I've been trying to see if it's at all salvageable.

Comment: in a perfect world, and with the setup I have, I'd want to test it on something I care 'less' about. I had an older PC for ages I'd use for testing, and this would be a perfect use for that.  Do you still have the broken rig? You could test it out on another slot and see if there's any issues (even at x8 or x4 speed) then try it on a system you care about

Comment: I actually just replaced the problematic motherboard because I was fearful of doing harm to the CPU, which was practically the only thing that came out unscathed from the ordeal. I'll see if I can't scrounge something together, though. Appreciate your insights!